# How to play MIDI files directly in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, midi

Is there a way to make Chrome able to play `.mid` files directly in the browser? For example, on [a Wikipedia page with MIDI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragtime_progression) there are many audio files in the right that are downloaded when clicking on them. The "help" page that is linked near the files is confusing and seems to only give the solution for `.ogg` files, for which Chrome has built-in support.

Is there any way to play these `.mid` files in browser just like `.ogg` files?

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: html5 + js do the trick. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168174/722135

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. [MIDI Player from the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midi-player/khppfbnjbaampmeeiocjhcodkklkcfjf?hl=en) appears to do just that. I haven't tried it personally but it claims to support .mid, .kar and .rmi formats. If you want to quickly test it, then go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MIDI_sample.mid?qsrc=3044.

Edit: I've tried it and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not.  The page must be coded differently.

When designing a web page, you can embed a javascript player so the midi file can be played by pushing the "play" button icon, but wikipedia and most sites just provide a link to the file.  This link gives greater detail on how to incorporate a player into a webpage, and also some descriptions of how various browsers have handled midi files over the years.

http://abcnotation.com/blog/2013/04/10/the-problem-with-midi/[enter link description here](http://abcnotation.com/blog/2013/04/10/the-problem-with-midi/)

From my research, none of the current browsers play midi file links automatically without installing extensions/plugins/addons/...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-midi-player/aagimlbccniocacfjiipcfagjpaigiab?hl=en-US

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midi-player/ggdnfelcdiebaofocemalnfclifhbfij?hl=en-US

extensions exist by now, exactly for this purpose! :)

Comment: I would like something like this, but which plays it to my MIDI device.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a plugin you can try out using a local player for the OS you are using. If you are on Windows you could set up file association for Midi files to, for instance Windows Media Player, and select 'Always Open Files of this type' (or similar worded choice in Chrome) for files like this sample URL (available in Windows 10 I believe);
file:///C:/windows/media/flourish.mid
This way the Windows Media Player will play the Midi file for you.

To associate .mid files to for instance Windows Media Player you can either do this through  Settings-Apps-Defaults-by File Type or through Shift-Right click on a .mid file and choose Open With default actions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want an external program (I usually use Noteworthycomposer or its viewer, NWCviewer, which is free), then the best solution is to use an extension for this.
I recommend Jazz-plugin, which you'll find here:

First install the Chrome extension:

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jazz-midi/jhdoobfdaejmldnpihidjemjcbpfmbkm?hl=en-US

Then install the global plug-in (required since Chrome refused NPAPI data):

> https://jazz-soft.net/download/Jazz-Plugin/

But you may prefer Midi Player:

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midi-player/khppfbnjbaampmeeiocjhcodkklkcfjf?hl=en-US

In both cases you will then be able to listen to midi files directly (and some other formats too).

This said, good sites include a midiplayer.

HTH!

Answer (score -1):

To answer it simply, NO because `.mid` or `MIDI` file contains the steps and patterns of a musical instrument being played and not the sounds of the instrument when that pattern is being played.

[@rsp explains it well on StackOverflow in this Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14039365/7975442)

Coming to Your Question

> Any way to play these .mid files in browser just like .ogg ?

There are a number of chrome extensions and Online MIDI player sites. Doing a Google Search will give you enough.

Comment: idk my browser was playing midi files natively in the 90s.